# Can I add in ajaxComplete a .js file.?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Can I add in ajaxComplete a .js file. I want to load js files after ajax is complete. Can I do this?

```
$( document ).ajaxComplete(function( event,request, settings ) {
    <script src="/static/js/app.js"></script>
}
```

Comment: You can't put HTML in Javascript. Use `$.loadScript()`.

Comment: ... well `$.loadScript()` isn't really a drop-in replacement for this (fictional) approach, is it?  The script has to be loaded and then something has to be explicitly invoked.

Comment: something like this?                             loadScript("http://your.cdn.com/second.js", function(){
       //initialization code
   });

Answer (score 0):

This is two steps. First: retrieve the scripting, then finally "evaluate" it.

**Since you're using jQuery, it is:**

```
$.get("/static/js/app.js")
   .done( function( contents ) {
       eval( contents )
   })
```

Comment: Okay thanks for your answers you all. I will look deeper in the code now. I still learning. Javascript quite difficult for me.

Comment: Well, that's a pretty advanced question, and I believe my answer solves it. I use the method above myself. Using `.done()` with `$.get` means that the AJAX request for the scripting is run, then once the scripting is downloaded, it is executed. BEWARE: If other things happen in the interface while the scripting is downloading, you might miss something. This is a very common consequence of "asynchronous" programming.